# Java GUI: I can't seem to add a JLabel without messing up my GridLayout?

Tags: java, user-interface, grid-layout

I'm trying to format my Java GUI using gridlayout, but I'm not sure where to start on formatting it. I don't have enough reputation to provide pictures, but I'd like my GUI to display an 8x8 grid on the left, and some JLabels on the right side. How would I go about doing that?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JButton; 
import java.awt.GridLayout; 
import java.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

import javax.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class ButtonGrid {

    JFrame frame=new JFrame(); //creates frame
    JButton[][] grid; //names the grid of buttons
    JLabel message;

    public ButtonGrid(int width, int length){ 
            frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(width,length)); //set layout
            grid=new JButton[width][length]; //size of grid
            int square =0;
            for(int y=0; y<length; y++){
                    for(int x=0; x<width; x++){
                            String squareString = String.valueOf(square);
                            grid[x][y]=new JButton(squareString); //makes newbutton   
                            frame.add(grid[x][y]); //adds button to grid
                            square++;
                    }
            }

            message = new JLabel("program is messing up");
            frame.add(message);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack(); //sets appropriate size for frame
            frame.setVisible(true); //makes frame visible
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            new ButtonGrid(8,8);//makes new ButtonGrid with 2 parameters
    }
}
```

So any help you guys can give would be really appreciated.

Comment: You can nest panels. 1) frame -default BorderLayout 2) (CENTER) panel with GridLayout 8x8 3) (EAST)panel with whatever layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GridLayout` is notoriously bad for stuff where you want spaces. Your best bet is either `GridBagLayout` (but it's overly complex for simple stuff like this), or nesting your views in other frames. You could put all those buttons onto a frame (call it `frameA`) with `GridLayout` like you are now, then add `frameA` to `frameB` (a parent frame). You could add the `JLabel` to `frameB` and have a guarantee that it wouldn't mess up the buttons. You could use a simple `BorderLayout` for `frameB` or a grid, or any other layout depending on what you need. Personally, I think it's so much easier to nest things in more frames because it makes layout far simpler. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Dylan, I'll give it a try. I'm super new to GUI, and this may take many attempts. I'll let you know how it works out.

Comment: Dylan, it worked. Thanks to everyone who replied. Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow, so is there a way I can like/credit your comments so that your reputation goes up or something?

Comment: Yes! Welcome. Click the outlined checkmark underneath my answer and if you want, vote my question up with the triangle buttons next to the score. Thanks for asking :)